# SQL: How to match two tables with multiple id fields

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table A and its structure looks like

```
MID  NAME
 98  hello
 99  world
```

Table B's structure is

```
FID ID1 ID2
1    99  99
2    99  98
3    98  99
```

I tried to match the ID1 and ID2 with MID to get the result like

```
1 world   world
2 world  hello
3 hello  world
```

How can I write the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table (TableA) twice, and give it aliases (a1, a2). The query then looks like this:

```
SELECT
  b.FID,
  a1.NAME,
  a2.NAME
from TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a1 ON a1.MID = b.ID1
INNER JOIN TableA a2 ON a2.MID = b.ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query table b and join table a on it twice, once for each id:

```
SELECT b.fid, a1.name, a2.name
FROM   b
JOIN   a AS a1 ON b.id1 = a1.mid
JOIN   a AS a2 ON b.id2 = a2.mid
```